# what's a powerful word replacement for "Desire" and "Yearning"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm searching for a replacement for "yearning" or "desire". Something that is power, fit for a burning, fiery description.

Originally I wanted to use 'a **yearning** brewing within..." and "a latent, dormant **desire** feels almost subconscious."

Please help. THanks!

Comment: You should simply use a thesaurus to look up synonyms of *desire*, and pick one that works for you. There are dozens. A very common one is *lust*. An uncommon one is *yen*. And there are many more in between.

Comment: In general, _ardor_ can be a useful synonym, although I don't think it work as a replacement for either example you give here.

Answer (score 1):

I would substitute it with ***hunger***, although I think that ***craving*** (as migs suggested) is also a good substitute

Answer (score 0):

You could try to substitute ***craving***.